# Bootstrap Dropdown-menu z-index error (overlapping)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

please, can you help me solve the overlapping issue with Bootstrap dropdown-menu?

[image: bad overlapping]

I have tried adding !important to z-index, adding overflow: hidden (saw it in other z-index issue topic), but no luck.

Here is the actual (not working) piece of CSS:

```
.header-progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 10px 20px 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
  z-index: 1001;
```

And here is full model on Codepen:
[Codepen - full code model](https://codepen.io/vlastapolach/pen/NgdMGG)

Any ideas please?

Comment: inside your .grey-back class add position and z-index styles: 
.grey-back {
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -400;
}

Comment: Thank you Vasyl - it solved the overlapping, but unfortunatelly made buttons un-clickable